# Convert String from XML to Array

Tags: powershell

I am setting up a unattended installation of a software with PowerShell.

If I use the following code to set an argument (`$Servers`) for the installer, the installation is OK:

```bsh
$Servers = "Server1.$($env:USERDNSDOMAIN)","Server2.$($env:USERDNSDOMAIN)"
```

But I want to get the settings from an external XML file like this one:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
  <Servers>"Server1.$($env:USERDNSDOMAIN)","Server2.$($env:USERDNSDOMAIN)"</Servers>
</Settings>
```

I use the following code to retrieve the data in Powershell:

```bsh
[Xml]$xmlConfigFile = Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\Settings.xml"
$Servers = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($xmlConfigFile.Settings.Servers)
```

This does NOT work. The install fails.
I think this is because I get a string back from the XML and not an array like in the first example above.
What is the best method to workaround the issue?

I thought about `.Split(",")`, but the quotes are a problem. I also tried `ConvertFrom-Csv`, but this didn't work either.

**EDIT:**
The output of the variable `$Servers` when it's working is:

```
Server1.domain.local
Server2.domain.local
```

The ouput of the variable `$Server` when coming from XML is:

```
"Server1.domain.local","Server2.domain.local"
```

Comment: Can you post the Output of `$Servers` after the last line?

Comment: `.Replace('"','').Split(',')`

Comment: Isn't there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Sure. Fix your input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the value you get from the XML data is a single string, not an array, so you need to split it to go from string to array. You could remove the double quotes before splitting the string (PowerShell allows you to daisy-chain method calls that return a value):

```bsh
$Servers = $Servers.Replace('"', '').Split(',')
```

However, a much better approach would be to fix your input data by putting the values in separate nodes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
  <Servers>
    <Server>Server1.$($env:USERDNSDOMAIN)</Server>
    <Server>Server2.$($env:USERDNSDOMAIN)</Server>
  </Servers>
</Settings>
```

so you can process the data like this:

```bsh
$Servers = $xmlConfigFile.Settings.Servers.Server | ForEach-Object {
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)
}
```

or like this:

```bsh
$Servers = $xmlConfigFile.SelectNodes('//Server') | ForEach-Object {
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_.'#text')
}
```

Comment: Of course you are right. That is much cleaner ;-)
I am not sure about the first method you posted. It's output is "System.Xml.XmlElement" !?
Thank you!

Comment: I think it should read "$Servers = $xmlConfigFile.Settings.Servers.Server". Am I right?

Comment: Correct. That was a copy/paste error on my part. Thanks for catching. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I did mark your post as answer.